# How to get logcat working on Intellij Idea on Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, intellij-idea

Logcat simply won't appear when I open a Flutter project on Intellij Idea 2020.3. I'm using it instead of Android Studio because of Docker support.

How can I see logcat?

[image]

Comment: Please try solutions from this thread: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16691

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View Menu -> Tool Windows -> logcat
```